# applying CSS3 Transitions on filters

Tags: html, css

I have a css3 filter that i wish to transition from one corner to another and not across board

```
div {-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); }
div:hover { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); }
```

I tried below but it changes across the board. Is there any way i can transition from one corner to another

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 1s;
```

Comment: I don't think you can tell the browser how to animate filters. Also IRRC webkit is the only browser which animates grayscale..

Comment: isnt there a radial or top-bottom option

Comment: For understanding purpose, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCwxe/).

Comment: There is a `radial-gradient` property, yes, @WebDeveloper, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Gradients and filters are different properties. You could transition both of them, which would result in colour draining in and out of the gradient. But because grayscale is not a sub-property of the gradient, you can't animate the grayscale as a gradient. Tell us what effect you're trying to achieve and we may be able to give further advice.

Comment: @enapupe you can tell browsers how to animate any numeric property via keyframes and the animation property or the transition property.

Comment: what i am referring is can this transition happen radially or in top to bottom fashion than all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken Zach answer and added:

```
.filtered:before {
    transition: 2s -webkit-mask-size;
    -webkit-mask-position: top left;
    -webkit-mask-size: 0px 0px;
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(131deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%); 
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.filtered:hover:before {
    -webkit-mask-size: 600px 600px;
}
```

Now there is a wipe effect from the upper left corner.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XARDP/2/)

Notice that still, we are not animating the filter in itself, but the transparency (inthat case the masking) of the layer that has the filter applied.

Also notice that you have a lot of ground to play with, creating different gradients to do the masking.

Also, the effect was little visible, so I have added a brightness factor to the grayscale (just for the demo)

Of course, all this limited to webkit

Answer (score 3):

Although filter is animatable as you show, it is impossible to transition from one corner to the other without duplicating the content and using a mask in addition. You can do so using pseudo-elements in certain cases, child element, or a sibling element.

I was *hoping* I could just use a pseudo-element with no content, place it over the original, and apply the filter to the pseudo-element and it affect the original beneath, but sadly that's not the case. This would allow the movement of the gray scale to go in any direction, size, or rotation you'd like without duplicating the content,  but apparently it only applies to the element it's on, not the elements below (which is understandable because it'd be difficult for browsers to tell what exactly it should re-color).

Onto the solution, the only way to transition from one corner to another is to use a mask as vals suggests. This still requires that the grey scale version be placed beneath the original, revealing it as it is hovered over

Filters will not work in FireFox or IE because [CSS filters don't have much support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). SVG filters for HTML, on the other hand, have [better support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html) and SVG filters on SVG [have even better support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters). If you can use these then that's like the better method at the moment. Using an SVG filter will likely also allow you to move the filter from side to side as you mentioned

Comment: Hi Zach ! Couldn't resist the posibility to upgrade your answer ... Anyway, you are right, that should be done with SVG.

Comment: @vals All of your answers > all of my answers, haha

Comment: you can apply transitions on filters. i ahve given a way in my question itself

Comment: So you can. Updated to suit